# Reuse change password from auth User

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have the following subclass:

```
class UserProfile(User):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, parent_link=True)
```

And an UserProfileAdmin:

```
class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # stuff
admin.site.register(UserProfile, UserProfileAdmin)
```

This admin displays a change password link `/admin/customer/userprofile/1548/password/` under the password field. But i get the following error:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1548/password'
```

I want to use the same change password form as in auth.User and after change is made i want to be redirected to UserProfileAdmin. How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the expected behavior because:

```
/admin/customer/userprofile/1548/password/
```

Wants to display the change form for userprofile with id '1548/password'.

Extending the User class is not the way to store extra data per user. Read the documentation on [Storing additional information about users](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) for instruction on how to do it the right way.

That said, you can if you want this url to open the admin change password page, you can do a redirect as such:

```
# put **before** include(admin.site.urls)
url(r'/admin/customer/userprofile/(?P<id>\d+)/password/$', 'views.redirect_to_password'),
```

And in views.py:

```
from django import shortcuts

def redirect_to_password(request, id):
    return shortcuts.redirect('/admin/auth/user/%s/password/' % id)
```

If you also want to redirect the /admin/auth/user/1234 to /admin/customer/userprofile/1234, then you could add this:

```
url(r'/admin/auth/user/(?P<id>\d+)/$', 'views.redirect_to_customer_changeform'),
```

Would work with a similar view:

```
from django import shortcuts

def redirect_to_customer_changeform(request, id):
    return shortcuts.redirect('/admin/customer/userprofile/%s/' % id)
```

Comment: I know it is not the way but i'm working on a big project in which extra data is stored in  this way

Comment: To change the user password, open /admin/auth/user/1548/password/ instead of /admin/customer/userprofile/1548/password/

Comment: I just tried it and it works. But I also want to be redirected back to UserProfileAdmin instead of auth/user...